# Why use auto-generated [HostType("ASP.NET")] when writing test cases?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, iis, testing

I am familiarizing myself with the asp.net C# unit test framework and I have quickly encountered issues when using the auto-generated stubs. For example VS2010 generates this methods:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [HostType("ASP.NET")]
    [AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("c:\\documents and settings\\ctremblay\\my documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\WebApplication2\\WebApplication2", "/")]
    [UrlToTest("http://localhost:3473/")]
    public void testmeTest()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); //FAILS here all the time
        test target = new test(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        bool testbool = false; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        bool expected = false; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        bool actual;
        actual = target.testme(testbool);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
    }
```

Based on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243172%28VS.80%29.aspx#DebuggingOnCassini

I should be able to add the System.Diagnostic method to debug within the IIS dev server but this fails on me everytime. This mean that debugging is impossible unless I remove the ASP/URL related annotations.

What do I have to gain using the annotations vs removing them completely?

Comment: I tried your scenario and it works for me. It does not fail on System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); Also make sure AspNetDevelopmentServerHost has the correct path. And of course Web.config <compilation debug="true"/>.

Comment: Hi Raj, thank you for trying it out. I will follow your advices and try it again tonight.